# Virasoro algebra

Tags: mathematical-physics

My question here is very computational. My problem is in mathematical physics, so I want to ask the community what kind of software they use to do the following computation if there is any? 
Let 
$$L_{n}=-\frac{n+1}{s} (u+v)n\frac{\partial}{\partial n} +\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} p_j (n+j)\frac{\partial}{\partial p_{n+j}}+\sum_{i+j=n}ij\frac{\partial^2}{\partial p_i \partial p_j} $$

For $n,m\geq 0$ it satisfies following equation 
 $$[L_m,L_n]=(m-n)L_{m+n} $$
where $[]$ denote the commutation bracket in Weyl algebra. That is $[\frac{\partial}{\partial p_{j}}, p_j]=1$ other wise all other combination commute. 
Notice that there infinitely many $p_i$.

Comment: You might have meant to ask this in [math.se]? This is a site for the computing software *Mathematica*, and so asking about *other* computing software is off-topic.

Comment: However, if you have tried to prove this identity using Mathematica software and encountered difficulties, please add your code to the question and ask for assistance.

Comment: You want a software in which you can evaluate commutators? Mathematica can do this with the [NCAlgebra package](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20435/non-commutative-algebra). Otherwise you can do these commutators by hand quite easily (at least symbolically, the details will depend on the domain of the differential operators).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this type of computation using the Maple Physics package; it supports commutator algebras, algebraic differential operators, tensorial non-commutative operators, etc. An example of a similar kind of calculation is presented in "[Quantum Runge-Lenz Vector and the Hydrogen Atom, the hidden SO(4) symmetry](https://www.mapleprimes.com/posts/208810-The-Hidden-SO4-Symmetry-Of-The-Hydrogen-Atom)", a step-by-step demonstration departing from basic principles using the kind of algebras and manipulation with differential operators you are asking about; at the end of it, there is a link to a PDF file with the steps visible. That post can give you an idea of how to formulate your problem.